# How to output flattened database tables to excel with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have four tables which are related through foreign keys.  `DriverStop` is the child of `DriverDailyRoute` and `Agency`.  `DriverDailyRoute` is the child of `User` (also known as `driver` in my relationship).  I want to flatten all of this data into one table so I can export it to excel.  I am having trouble doing this. The code bellow works.

```
@app.route('/admin/dumpdb')
@admin_filter
def admin_dump_db():
    query = model.DriverStop.query.join(model.DriverDailyRoute, model.Agency).join(model.User).all()
    print(query[0].route.driver.username)
    cols = ['dairy']
    return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(query, cols, "xls")
```

In this case dairy is a column in the `DriverStop` table.  But how do I access columns in the `DriverDailyRoute` or `User` table?  I tried to change cols to `cols = ['route.driver.first_name']` but this gives an error.  How can I fix this?

Also is there a way to change the display name of the columns in the excel file like `cols=[('Dairy Collected', 'dairy')]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using with_entities() method.
Try to change the query like this:

```
query = model.DriverStop.query.with_entities(DriverStop.id, DriverDailyRoute.name, User.first_name).join(model.DriverDailyRoute, model.Agency).join(model.User).all()
```

Inside the with_entities method, you can list all columns which you want to export to excel.
Of course, in the query above I supposed that your models have following attributes:

- DriverStop - id attribute,
- DriverDailyRoute - name attribute and
- User - first_name attribute

Of course, you have to use only attributes which your models have.

And your cols variable should look like this:

```
cols = ['id', 'name', 'first_name']
```

Comment: thanks, too late for the OP, not for me :)